# Display dialog box when application close from android code

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am getting problem data loss during application close, is there any idea when user close application any action(like click menu or back button) , I want to display message when actually application close in one step, not back button for different activity.

if i have 5 activity , i want to one step know application close , user running any activity among 5.but here i used back button each 5 activity but i want to one step, and if user click menu at that , i also display message you are going to close application.

Comment: Why do you want to implement a close function? You should look into your data loss and fix the problem that way and not implement another close function in order to save yourself. Look into how to store your data correctly and the lifecycles of your 5 activities.

Comment: You shouldn't bother the user with a dialog "Are you sure you want to exit?".. Rather save your data in persistent storage and exit without asking. When user launches your app again, restore the data. This is the same as saving and restoring the data when the screen rotates. **Android is not Windows.** I really dislike apps that ask this question. Toasting "Press back again to exit" is bearable but still not ideal.

Comment: What if the user gets a phone call? You aren't guaranteed to be able to interact with the user before they leave the app.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Activity class as a BaseActivity and extend it in all 5 activities.
Then override onBackPressed method in BaseActivity.
This way you have not to copy your logic in 5 (or more places).